# after installing hplip 3.20.6 recieve communication error 5012

Tags: printing

i found out that my system is missing this driver'/usr/lib/cups/-filter/hpcups. How can i add this so my printer will work. can it be installed via the terminal I installed it in ubuntu 20.04 but i keep getting device communication 5012.

Answer (score 2):

In terminal, type:

```
sudo apt-get install printer-driver-hpcups
```

If that works, please consider marking this question answered or up-voting. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you. It works for me.